# Wait until in Select element using selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python

In my test, I need to wait for text until it will be loaded.

I have a list of countries and cities. After I choice country I must wait until cities will be loaded. How I can wait without `time.sleep()`?

```
time.sleep(2)

select_country = Select(self.browser.css("#country_id"))
select_country.select_by_visible_text("Russia")

time.sleep(2)

select_city = Select(self.browser.css("#city_id"))
select_city.select_by_visible_text("Moscow")
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML source?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use **Explicit Wait:**
An explicit wait is a code you define to wait for a certain condition to occur before proceeding further in the code.

*OPTION-1:*

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
select_country = Select(self.browser.css("#country_id"))
select_country.select_by_visible_text("Russia")

city = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#city_id")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
city_dropDown = wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located(city))
select_city = Select(city_dropDown)
select_city.select_by_visible_text("Moscow")
```

---

*OPTION-2:*

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

select_country = Select(self.browser.css("#country_id"))
select_country.select_by_visible_text("Russia")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_selected(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#city_id")))
select_city = Select(element)
select_city.select_by_visible_text("Moscow")
```

---

*OPTION-3:*

```
select_country = Select(self.browser.css("#country_id"))
select_country.select_by_visible_text("Russia")

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "city"))
//---------use other element locators too like xpath/css_selector/css_name
    )
finally:
    select_city = Select(element)
    select_city.select_by_visible_text("Moscow")
```

---

*OPTION-4:*

You can also try with **Implicit Waits:**

An implicit wait tells WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find any element (or elements) not immediately available.

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
select_country = Select(self.browser.css("#country_id"))
select_country.select_by_visible_text("Russia")
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
select_city = Select(self.browser.css("#city_id"))
select_city.select_by_visible_text("Moscow")
```

Comment: Good one....! 
I'm also searching for the same issue & Now fixed with the above code. Thanks, @Bharat.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `waits` that Selenium provides you in order to wait for countries to load. You can either use `implicit wait` or `explicit wait` (recommended).

Please [read](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) the Selenium documentation for more information.